# NuGet uses different config files

Tags: c#, jenkins, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a problem regarding the used nuget.config.
If i start a nuget restore via command line nuget uses

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
```

If the nuget restore is triggered via a jenkins build job it uses

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
```

Can somebody tell me where nuget stores the information which config is uses?

Comment: This information is not stored anywhere. The path depends on which user starts the nuget-process (localsystem or a specific user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet resolves the configs each time it runs. 
It's going to AppDataRoaming for the user, C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config, and it will try walking up the configs up the chain from the location of the project being restored. 
You're likely running as an admin in the above CI case.

Namely, if your folder structure is such:

```
F:\CoolApp\CoolProject\CoolProject.csproj
F:\CoolApp\CoolProject\NuGet.Config
F:\CoolApp\NuGet.Config
```

You could end up with the following configs, loaded in priority order:

```
F:\CoolApp\CoolProject\NuGet.Config
F:\CoolApp\NuGet.Config
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config
```

The correct approach here would be to specify your config when building restoring.